# How to extract (First match)text between two words

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file having the following structure

```
destination list

move from station d-435-435 to point place1
move from station d-435-435 to point place2
move from mainpoint
```

I want to extract the word "`d-435-435`"(Only the first match, this need not be same value always) in between the words "`from station`" and "`to point`"

How can I achieve this?

What I have tried so far?

`id=$(sed 's/.*from station \(.*\) to.*/\1/' input.txt)`

But this returns the following value: `destination list d-435-435 move from mainpoint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following GNU `awk` code. Using `match` function of `awk` program here to match regex `rom station\s+\S+\s+to point` to get requested value by OP then removing `from station\s+` and `\s+to point` from matched value and printing required value.

```
awk '
match($0,/from station\s+\S+\s+to point/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/from station\s+|\s+to point/,"",val)
  print val
  exit
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` please try following. Using `-oP` option to print matched portion and enabling PCRE regex respectively here. Then in main `grep` program matching string `from station` followed by space(s) then using `\K` option will make sure matched part before `\K` is forgotten(since e don't need this in output), Then matching `\S+`(non space values) followed by space(s) `to point` string(using positive look ahead here to make sure it only checks its present or not but doesn't print that).

```
grep -oP -m1 'from station\s+\K\S+(?=\s+to point)' Input_file
```

Comment: Nice answer, but please let me add some comments. First, `\s` and `\S`
are  GNU extension and might be better to use `[[:blank:]]`
and `[^[:blank:]]` for the POSIX compatibility. Second, the OP
wants to extract the first match only. Then how about putting `exit`
after the `print val` line. Cheers!

Comment: @tshiono, thanks buddy. I had exit in it but while editing I made typo, please do check if this looks fine now cheers

Comment: Oh, I see :). It works great and ++ed for the nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

If GNU sed is available, how about:

```
id=$(sed -nE '0,/from station.*to/ s/.*from station (.*) to.*/\1/p' input.txt)
```

- The `-n` option suppress the print unless the substitution succeeds.
- The condition `0,/pattern/` is a flip-flop operator and it returns false
  after the pattern match succeeds. The 0 address is a GNU sed extension which
  makes the 1st line to match against the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you can write the before and after conditions of
field $4, where `d-435-435` is, and then print this field `only the first match` and exit with `exit` after `print` statement:

```
awk '$2=="from" && $3=="station" && $5=="to" && $6=="point" {print $4; exit}' file
d-435-435
```

or using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
awk 'match($0,/from station\s+(.*)\s+to point/,a){print a[1];exit}' file
d-435-435
```

- The regexp contains a parenthesis, so the integer-indexed element of array `a[1]` contain the portion of string between `from station` followed by space(s) `\s+` and space(s) `\s+` followed by`to point`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/.*station (\S+) to point.*/{s//\1/;H;x;/\n(\S+)\n.*\1/{s/\n\S+$//;x;d};x;p}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing and on extended regexps command line options `-nE`.

If a line matches the required criteria, extract the required string, append a copy to the hold space, check if the match has already been seen and if not print it. If the match has been seen, remove it from the hold space.

Otherwise, do not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in any `sed`:

```
sed -e '/.*from station \([^ ]*\) to .*/!d' -e 's//\1/' -e q file
```